# Is it possible to use Regex in HTML?

Tags: java, html, regex

Alright, I am really new into this and might be a stupid question but I have a word "kirtna" that appears in more than 1000 HTML files that are saved in my assets folder. It's in proper HTML file format which was pasted into Mac's TextEdit and saved to HTML. Now I want the alphabet 'a' to be appeared before 'n'. So instead of "kirtna" it should be "kirtan". I know I can do that Java itself using Regex such as below:

```
String word = "instant";
String replaced = input.replaceAll("(\\w)a", "a$1");
```

But can I really do this in HTML?

Comment: Look at the answer with 4k upvotes. You will soon see. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: HTML is NOT a programming language. It just describes structure of website.

Comment: @Chris That's... amazing...

Comment: @chrylis It's difficult explaining to colleagues why I'm crying with laughter in the middle of work. That post has nearly cost me my job once or twice!

Answer (score 5):

Well, I don't know how do you want to use this in "HTML", which is not a programming language...

One way to achieve this would be to use a text editor like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), which is able to do text replacement in a given folder (with regex if you need).

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use Regex in HTML?

The answer is: not really.

HTML5 [Input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) has a "pattern" Attribute, which could be used for pattern matching / Validation.

For your job, it would be best to use Javascript's [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AW7XH/) to play with.

```
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("blur", function(e){
    var textBox=e.target;
    textBox.value=textBox.value.replace("a","blabla");
});
```